# rspec with different DNS server

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, infrastructure

I have a bunch of rspec test which uses external databases (I know, this is not a good idea, but there are a lot of reasons this is the best solution in this case). I've set up a different vlan with a test environment to run the tests within a isolated environment. Now I want to define that all rspec tests use a different DNS server to resolve the hostnames (to work with the dev environment). Is there something I can use?

Comment: DNS resolver settings are usually configured at OS level so I don't think there's anything you can do. I know this is not helpful but the best and probably only way is to fix your specs so they don't call any external systems. Use Mocks or something. Tools like VCR (https://github.com/vcr/vcr) can help you with external calls.

Comment: Not sure this helps, but if you used the IPs you could use something like http://xip.io/

Answer (score 1):

RubyDNS might work for you. This example is almost verbatim from their GH page:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubydns'

INTERFACES = [
  [:udp, "0.0.0.0", 5300],
  [:tcp, "0.0.0.0", 5300]
]
Name = Resolv::DNS::Name
IN = Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN

# Use upstream DNS for name resolution.
UPSTREAM = RubyDNS::Resolver.new([[:udp, "8.8.8.8", 53], [:tcp, "8.8.8.8", 53]])

# start the RubyDNS server
RubyDNS::run_server(:listen => INTERFACES) do
    match(/database\.testing\.com/, IN::A) do |transaction|
        transaction.respond!("10.0.0.80")
    end

    # Default DNS handler
    otherwise do |transaction|
        transaction.passthrough!(UPSTREAM)
    end
end
```

then to query:

```
➜  ruby_dns_example  dig @localhost -p 5300 database.testing.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @localhost -p 5300 database.testing.com
; (3 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34286
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;database.testing.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
database.testing.com.   86400   IN  A   10.0.0.80

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#5300(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 31 13:14:14 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

There are lots of examples here:

https://github.com/ioquatix/rubydns/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use DnsMock instead. It's testing framework agnostic, lightweight UDP DNS mock server with dynamic/manual port assignment: https://github.com/mocktools/ruby-dns-mock

```rb
require 'dns_mock'

records = {
  'example.com' => {
    a: %w[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2],
    aaaa: %w[2a00:1450:4001:81e::200e],
    ns: %w[ns1.domain.com ns2.domain.com],
    mx: %w[mx1.domain.com mx2.domain.com],
    txt: %w[txt_record_1 txt_record_2],
    cname: 'some.domain.com',
    soa: [
      {
        mname: 'dns1.domain.com',
        rname: 'dns2.domain.com',
        serial: 2_035_971_683,
        refresh: 10_000,
        retry: 2_400,
        expire: 604_800,
        minimum: 3_600
      }
    ]
  },
  '1.1.1.1' => {
    ptr: %w[domain_1.com domain_2.com]
  }
}

DnsMock.start_server(records: records, port: 5300)
```